# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>video_id=89'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mariadb, laravel-query-builder

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I am unable to delete the notification using the below query. It gives the following error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>video_id=89'
>   at line 1 (SQL: delete from `notifications` where data->video_id=89).

`DB::table('notifications')->WhereRaw("data->video_id=$video_id")->delete();`

Comment: Whence is `data` in your query?  Are you trying to do a delete join?

Comment: because in notification table it stores data like this.    "data": {
        "video_id": 89    
    }

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using data->video_id

Just try with

```
WhereRaw("video_id=$video_id")
```

Comment: `WhereRaw != Where`. This wrong https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: because in notification table it stores data like this. "data": { "video_id": 89 }.

Comment: OP is trying to query inside a JSON object. In Laravel, you use the `->` operator in the query, but only if the underlying database supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` operator is shorthand for the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function in MySQL. Unfortunately, MariaDB does not support this shorthand syntax.

MariaDB did introduce the JSON_* functions in 10.2.3, but I do not know if they will work on columns in a query. Best thing you can do is try. You will need to rewrite your query to explicitly use the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function:

```
DB::table('notifications')
    ->whereRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.video_id") = ?', [$video_id])
    ->delete();
```

If this doesn't work, then you'll either need to switch from MariaDB to MySQL, or you'll need to rewrite your query as a simple string search (using the `LIKE` operator).

Comment: above query gives the error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION wittylab_wittylab.JSON_EXTRACT does not exist (SQL: delete from `notifications` where JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.video_id") = 89)"

Comment: @MD.MazharulIslam That means you're either not on MariaDB >=10.2.3, or that function doesn't work in queries. Either way, looks like you'll have to use a plain text search (`LIKE` operator)